# Using express-jwt, why is my authorization header missing when it's clearly there

Tags: node.js, authentication, token, express-jwt

I am using express-jwt along with jsonwebtoken.

When I try to use jsonwebtoken.verify(), I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid token: no header in signature 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOi...reallylongtoken...
... more ...
code: 'MISSING_HEADER'
```

I can see that the req.headers.authorization token exists because I'm logging it out.  So I don't understand why the header is missing if it's clearly there.

Any help appreciated.
here's the gist:
https://gist.github.com/ryanore/914362881d2d9f0878f2

Here's the console.log output for req.headers.authorization

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NDhhMGFkODcwZWZjZmMwM2EwMDAwMDEiLCJjcmVhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDE0LTEyLTExVDIxOjIxOjI4LjI0M1oiLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiIiLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6IiIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoicnlhbm9yZSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiJDJhJDEwJFM0YjcyVzIyQS9ubDJxZXV0WUxsUk9SNWhIblhvTGxkT09ud096OTFVNzBvSDVIQXRGZFhTIiwiZW1haWwiOiIiLCJfX3YiOjB9.fiHZ1J7cLXtgurTvqGVP2RcJqpju1zNmXBETWqYKXko
```

Comment: Can you update your question and include the console.log output of `req.headers.authorization` directly? It's likely the issue is that something in there is not working properly. If we see that directly we can debug it easier =)

Comment: Thanks for quick response,I added the output.

Answer (score 2):

I had to unaccept @rdegges answer because I jumped the gun a little bit.  It was very helpful to discover the debugger, but it was of little actual help in solving my problem.

The answer is actually simple.  I was sending the whole Authorization header when I needed to split off the 'Bearer ' part of it.  I got the idea from [This blog](http://www.spaceinvade.rs/2014/08/16/MEAN-stack-with-CouchDB-express4-angularjs/).  After removing the 'Bearer ' part it verified fine.

Here's the updated function if it's helpful to anyone else.

```
exports.verify = function(req, res) {
  var token = null;
  var bits = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');

  if (bits.length == 2) {
        var scheme = bits[0];
        var credentials = bits[1];
        if (/^Bearer$/i.test(scheme)) {
            token = credentials;
            jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function(err, decoded){
                if(err)     sendStatus(res, 401);
            });
        } 
    } 
    else{
        sendStatus(res, 401);
    }
};
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this seemed to have worked for me, but it seems very strange. Why set `Bearer` in the request if we're just going to ignore it on the receiving end?

Comment: @MichaelLynch,  when I was doing this I was following this tutorial and that tutorial and I never really stopped to ask that question.  In my case, I was rolling my own authentication so I can't think of any reason it's necessary.

That said,  this is a convention used in the Oauth standard, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749, and a lot of frameworks follow this convention because of that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that your signature is invalid.

I tested this by taking your Authorization header output, and copy+pasting it into the JWT debugger at: http://jwt.io

As you can see in the screenshot below, there are some errors.

Best!

[image: JWT Debugging]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the tool.  I'm new to jwt.  Cheers!

Comment: No problem! It's quite confusing when you're getting started! Good luck on your adventure.

Comment: It's invalid because you didn't enter the secret... though that tool is useful, this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but in the screenshot of the jwt from @rdegges answer, it looks like you are including the the password with the user details. You shouldn't send the password in the jwt (even though it is hashed it is unnecessary) or any sensitive data.

You can avoid having it returned if you add "selected: false" to your mongoose user schema in the password field. If you do that, use the '+password' notation in the find method for login (as in):

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, '+password', function(err, user) {
.... <<enter code to check if credentials are correct>> }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool! never seen that.  Yeah this really should be a comment, but thanks.